# configure port for dhcp request in uboot

Tags: dhcp, u-boot, lfs

We are fetching ip using DHCP in u-boot. we need to send via same  interface (eg eth1) every time. but DHCP request sent via any configured interface(eth1/eth2..). How can we configure u-boot to send DHCP request only on particular interface.